ReactSelect Component Shows Ghosted Values
CustomReactSelect is displaying some values that seem to be the previous thought the values were updated

I've logged the value of the items and the value is correct but for some reason this "previous" selected options keep showing and lose their value. It appends when changing chats, I expect the members to be updated according to the new clicked chat.
The options are always the same
<CustomReactSelect
    instanceID="chat-members"
    hintText={translate("chat_members", user?.language)}
    multiple={true}
    user={user}
    colors={Colors}
    options={connectedUsers}
    selectedItems={groupUsers}
    onChange={updateGroupUsers}
/>

And this is what happens when a new chat is selected
useEffect(() => {
    if (chat) {
        setGroupUsers(chat.users);
    }
}, [chat])

